# get return value of command run with script -c

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to capture the return value of a program run using script -c?

For example (in bash)

```
/bin/false; echo $? # outputs 1

/usr/bin/script -c "/bin/false" /dev/null; echo $? 
# outputs 0 as script exited successfully.
```

I need to get the return value from /bin/false instead of from /usr/bin/script.. is this possible? I'm using script to trick a program into thinking it is running in a real tty even though it isn't... Thanks!

Comment: according to `man script`, there seems that adding `-e` option can return the exit code of the child process.

Comment: wow I must need more coffee.. I must have read the man page 3 times and somehow missed that... thank you!

Comment: I searched the page for the word "return" and found it in a few seconds.

Comment: yeah i think this was a case of staring at the screen so long I couldn't read what was right in front of me anymore... anyway @ymonad if you want to "answer" the question I'll happily mark it as the answer so you get a point!

Comment: Please post that as an answer, so that OP can close the question.. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `man script`, using `-e` option will return the exit code of the child process.

```
-e, --return
       Return the exit code of the child process.
       Uses the same format as bash termination 
       on signal termination exit code is 128+n.
```

Here's some example.

```
  $ /usr/bin/script -e -c "/bin/false" /dev/null; echo $?
  1
  $ /usr/bin/script -e -c "/bin/true" /dev/null; echo $?
  0
  $ /usr/bin/script -e -c "exit 123" /dev/null; echo $?
  123
```